# How to compare pairs of columns in awk?

Tags: awk

I have the following dataset from a pairwise analysis (the first row are just the sample ids):

```
A B A C
1 1 1 0
1 2 1 1
1 0 1 2
```

I wish to compare the values for `field 1` and `field 2` then `field 3` and `field 4` such that I want to print the row number `NR` every time I see a `1` and `2` combination for the pairs I am examining.

For example for pairs `A` and `B`, I would want the output:

```
A B 2
```

For pairs `A` and `C`, I would want the output:

```
A C 3
```

I would want to proceed row by row so I would likely need the code to include:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    awk 'NR=="'${i}'" {code}'
done
```

But I have no idea how to proceed in a pairwise fashion (i.e. compare `field 1` and `field 2` and then `field 3` and `field 4` etc...).

How can I do this?

Comment: If there are ten lines of data out of a hundred containing `1 2` in the `A B` columns, how do you want the result printed?  Suppose there are also fifteen lines out of a hundred containing `1 2` in the `A C` columns; how do you want the result printed.

Comment: Why do you have 2 columns with the same name, A? Do those columns always contain the same data as each other? Does it matter which "A" we compare "B" or "C" against? If it does, how does a script know which you want it to use? It it doesn't why have 2 of them?

Comment: @EdMorton, it does not matter which "A" as they will be the same for every comparison.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ideally, I would want the sample ids followed by the row that the 1 2 is found concatenated together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say with such a minimal example but this MAY be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR==1 {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        name[i] = $i
    }
    next
}
{
    for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) {
        if ( ($i == 1) && ($(i+1) == 2) ) {
            print name[i], name[i+1], NR-1
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
A B 2
A C 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you please explain the first portion of the `awk` script? I don't quite understand `let [i]=$i`

Comment: `let` is an array holding the letters found in the first line of the file.  It is unrelated to the keyword LET used in some languages to introduce an assignment.

Comment: changed `let` to `name` to remove that confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly should only run the script once; there's no need to run `awk` more frequently.  It isn't yet entirely clear how you want multiple matches printed.  However, if you're working a line at time, then the output probably comes a line at a time.

Working on that basis, then:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { for (i = 1; i < NF; i += 2)
               { cols[(i+1)/2,1] = $i; cols[(i+1)/2,2] = $(i+1); } 
               next
             }
             { for (i = 1; i < NF; i += 2)
               { if ($i == 1 && $(i+1) == 2)
                     print cols[(i+1)/2,1], cols[(i+1)/2,2], NR - 1
               }
             }'
```

The `NR == 1` block of code captures the headings so they can be used in the main printing code.  There are plenty of other ways to store the information too.  The other block of code looks at the data lines and checks that pairs of fields contain `1 2` and print out the control data if there is a match.  Because NF will be an even number, but the loops count on the odd numbers, the `<` comparison is OK.  Often in `awk`, you use `for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)` with a single increment and then `<=` is required for correct behaviour.

For your minimal data set, this produces:

```
A B 2
A C 3
```

For this larger data set:

```
A B A C
1 1 1 0
1 2 1 1
1 0 1 2
1 2 4 2
5 3 1 9
7 0 3 2
1 2 1 0
9 0 1 2
1 2 3 2
```

the code produces:

```
A B 2
A C 3
A B 4
A B 7
A C 8
A B 9
```